# jQuery datepicker w/ script to disable dates, works in fiddle. not on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, datepicker, disabled-input

Here's the code I've got in the HEAD of my site (header.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var unavailableDates = ["1-9-2013", "2-9-2013", "3-9-2013", "4-9-2013", "5-9-2013"];

function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

    $(function() {
        $("#dpick").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });

});
```

When I load it into fiddle and call a simple input using the specific ID referenced in the 2nd function (#dpick) it works fine and disables the dates September 1-5 2013 in the datepicker - so the script itself seems to be OK.

But when I use it on my website (my site is in WordPress and the datepicker field is inside of a ContactForm7 form - if that makes any difference - it still lets me set the ID of the datepicker field so it should be fine) none of the dates are disabled.

The datepicker field is called "Tour Date" (in the left column, 2nd row from the bottom) - even when I view the source of the page, I can see my JS being declared in the head and if I scroll down to where the form fields are, I can see that my tour date (datepicker) field ID is set to id="dpick" which should work based on the 2nd function in my script, right?

Can anyone help me figure out why this isn't working? I've been trying to figure this out for ages and haven't had any luck. I feel like I'm on the right track but maybe I'm missing something simple...

Edit:

Not sure if this makes any difference...but in the 2nd function where it says "dateFormat: 'dd MM yy'" - there's also an option to set the date format from within my CF7 form, but I've tried matching them up and even then it still doesn't seem to work... :/

Answer (score 2):

You're including jQuery *after* your script, which uses jQuery. Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var unavailableDates = ["1-9-2013", "2-9-2013", "3-9-2013", "4-9-2013", "5-9-2013"];

    function unavailable(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

    // snip... more code...

    // you're using jQuery! but it's not loaded yet!
    $(function() {
        $("#dpick").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm dd yy',
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
    });
</script>

<!-- more HTML stuff... -->

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://experience.nipissingu.ca/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://experience.nipissingu.ca/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://experience.nipissingu.ca/wp-content/plugins/gallery-plugin-pro/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js?ver=3.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://experience.nipissingu.ca/wp-content/plugins/gallery-plugin-pro/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js?ver=3.6'></script>
<!-- etc. more jQuery including -->
```

Simply move your script tag *after* the jQuery includes, and it will work.

You can see that you have an error in the JavaScript console:

[image]

Comment: Hi Doorknob, I moved the script below the jQuery includes and made sure that it's being called after in the source, but it's still not disabling the dates...any ideas? :/

Comment: @Iconoclast Look in your error console. I see an error there.

Comment: I see the error too...but I don't know how to fix! I already moved the script below where I'm calling jQuery...it has something to do with the first function but I don't understand

Comment: @Iconoclast Hint: there's something wrong with the way the `datepicker` library is being included - the error is telling you that it couldn't be found.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do this is to put your JavaScript in a file: `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/js/your-script.js` and enqueue it in `functions.php` adding jQuery as a dependency. This way, other plugins can interact with your script, e.g.: caching plugins.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_so_18343752' );

function enqueue_so_18343752() 
{
    wp_register_script( 
        'my-datepicker', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/your-script.js', 
        array( 'jquery' ) // Dependencies
    );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-datepicker' );
}
```

I tested with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{   
    alert('enqueued successfully');
}
```

but your file **your-scripts.js** should look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
{   
    var unavailableDates = ["1-9-2013", "2-9-2013", "3-9-2013", "4-9-2013", "5-9-2013"];

    function unavailable(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
            return [true, ""];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
        }
    }

    $(function() {
        $("#dpick").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi brasofilo, I tried this but it didn't work - in fact, it produced a "server error" message where I couldn't even load my website. It was something to do with adding the first section of code to the functions.php file, since the error only happened when I uploaded that file. I uploaded my JS file (containing the second section of code) to my theme folder, in the /library/js/ directory...is this the right place? Also, I'm using a child theme, if that makes any difference. Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried adding it again and it's doing the same thing - "server error" message. I copied and pasted 2nd section into new file called "disableddates.js" and uploaded to `wp-content/themes/magazino/library/js/` (there was a syntax error with this code...I had to add `});` to the end for it to compile) then I added 1st section into `functions.php` file at the very bottom, updated the filename to "disableddates.js" and also removed the very last `?>` but it's still giving me server error message

Comment: Sure, here's the `functions.php` file: http://pastebin.com/q32Q7e53 (the function I copied & pasted from your answer above is at the very bottom, and I replaced the last `?>` because it was missing without it). Then here's what my `disableddates.js` file looks like: http://pastebin.com/F0xrSi5E so my `functions.php` file lives in `/wp-content/themes/magazino_child/` while the `disableddates.js` file lives in `/wp-content/themes/magazino/library/js/`

Comment: I tried putting functions.php in the parent theme folder instead of the child, but it didn't seem to change anything. The only other 2 things I can think of (based on research I did on these errors) is that I should replace `$` with `jQuery` because it can conflict with WordPress using jQuery elsewhere...but when I do this, I get a JS error in console that says something like "$("#dpick").datepicker() is not a function

Comment: Someone on a forum also said to make sure that the datepicker function is being called AFTER the datepicker on the page. But I'm not sure how this is possible, since my datepicker input is inside the CF7 form in my WordPress site...and don't I have to call the jQuery/JS from the head?

Comment: Sorry, I can only help with properly enqueuing jQuery and custom scripts. On my end, that was all the help I can offer. Hope you find what else is going wrong in your project, good luck! PS: I removed my previous comments.